# How to capture hbase cluster metrics for monitoring purpose using ELK stack?

Tags: hbase, monitoring

**I am not able to find rest api end points where xml format metric can be retrieved.**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using a document based database for metrics. It doesn't scale well and causes issues in managing the data. There are lots of commercial tools out there which can do this (AppDynamics, Datadog, and many others). If you want OSS, this stack is probably the best currently (Prometheus and Grafana). http://rokroskar.github.io/monitoring-spark-on-hadoop-with-prometheus-and-grafana.html <- Good blog showing the setup.

Comment: Thanks Jonah for replying.

Comment: I have used CDH and Ambari for monitoring bigdata stack before.This time required something different for my company to monitor plain vanilla apache binaries without using distribution.I tried ganglia and able to monitor hadoop and hbase but stuck with other apache binaries.Than i came across ELK stack to monitor binaries.I have also looked into datadog and sematext but those are paid. Prometheus and grafana shows monitoring of spark application. will it also monitor other apache binaries easily ?